# Use Javascript buttons to show a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set up some buttons to show and hide a certain `<div>`. However I've had trouble reversing the function. When you load up the page, the `<div>` is shown, but I want the `<div>` to be hidden and only show when the button is clicked.

```js
function yes() {
      var x = document.getElementById("yes");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="yes()">I support</button>
<div id="yes">Text</div>
```

So I still want the button to work the same, toggling the `<div>` on and off, but I want the `<div>` to be hidden until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `<div>` start off hidden when the page loads, this can be done by adding the inline styling, `style="display: none"`

```
<div style="display: none" id="yes">
```

So the `<div>` will remain hidden until the button is clicked.